# How do I get different elements from a string with count method

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, count

I'm trying to create a script which gives some information. I need to count the elements from a list asked to the user. But I'm having problems with some elements.

For example, given a DNA sequence, I need the length, the number of nucleotides and their type. For instance, in a sequence like: `AATTAaCCGg` the output should be:

```
Adenine = 4 (count A and a)
Thymine = 2
Cytosine = 2 
Guanine = 2
```

This is where I am stuck:

```
sequence = str(input('Enter DNA sequence:'))
print ('Your sequence contain:',len(secuencia), 'bases', 'with the following structure:')
adenine = sequence.count("A" or "a")
thymine = sequence.count("T" or "t")
cytosine = sequence.count("C" or "c")
guanine = sequence.count ("G" or "g")

print("adenine = ", adenine)
print("thymine = ", thymine)
print("cytosine = ", cytosine)
print("guanine = ", guanine)
```

But the `sequence.count` part doesn't differentiate between "A" and "a". I tried with "and" and "or" structures but it doesn't seem to work.

By the way, this can this be solved with a dictionary like this one:

```
dicc = {adenine:"A" and "a", thymine:"T" and "t",
       cytosine:"C" and "c", guanine:"G" and "g"}
```

Comment: Whats with all the " ` " marks. You don't need those if you are using the code formatting.

Comment: Should not be `Adenine = 4 (count A and a)` in the sample (as I count 4 A)?

If so, you can use `sequence.lower()` method and then count the 'a' only and so on.

Answer (score 1):

what would be wrong with `adenine = sequence.count("A") + sequence.count("a")` ?

The thing is that the `or` is not going to be accepted as an argument to the `sequence.count` function.  Python is going to evaluate `or` as a logical operator.  strings like `"A"` and `"a"` are "truthy" values.  So, what ends up happening here is that you are calling `sequence.count(True)`, and that is almost certainly not giving you the results you expect.

Without creating your own function to count the number of times `"A"` or `"a"` shows up in a string, then you should be dealing with the returned values.  Here they are integers, so you can simply add them.  It will mean that the program has to search the string twice to find the characters, but that doesn't matter for a program like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just find separately and sum up:

```
...
adenine = sequence.count("A") + sequence.count("a")
thymine = sequence.count("T") + sequence.count("t")
cytosine = sequence.count("C") + sequence.count("c")
guanine = sequence.count ("G") + sequence.count("g")
...
```

Or make all string lower case, then count:

```
...
sequence.lower()
adenine = sequence.count("a")
thymine = sequence.count("t")
cytosine = sequence.count("c")
guanine = sequence.count("g")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the occurrence of each letter:

```
import collections

sequence = input('Enter a DNA sequence: ')
counter = collections.Counter(sequence)
print(counter)
```

For instance:

```
Enter a DNA sequence: AATTAaCCGg
Counter({'A': 3, 'C': 2, 'T': 2, 'G': 1, 'a': 1, 'g': 1})
```

But if you consider that "A" is similar to "a", you can ignore the casing:

```
sequence = input('Enter a DNA sequence: ')
counter = collections.Counter(sequence.upper())
print(counter)
```

You get:

```
Enter a DNA sequence: AATTAaCCGg
Counter({'A': 4, 'C': 2, 'T': 2, 'G': 2})
```

Comment: yeah its quite a good solution, but it can interfer with your results when the DNA sequence include letters which are not neither A T C G nor a t c g

Comment: @Fence Of course, but it is another problem you can check easily: `assert all(c.upper() in "ACTG" for c in sequence)`.

Answer (score -1):

You should count like this. Maybe a little bit overkill, but it's clear as water.

```
sequence=input('Give me a DNA:')
count_a = 0
count_t = 0
count_c = 0
count_g = 0

for each_letter in sequence.lower():
    if 'a' in each_letter:
        count_a += 1
    elif 't' in each_letter:
        count_t += 1
    elif 'c' in each_letter:
        count_c += 1
    elif 'g' in each_letter:
        count_g += 1

print('The counters are: \n -%s \n -%s \n -%s \n -%s \n', (count_a,count_t,count_c,count_g))
```

Comment: totally overkill. OP `should not` do like this and how is it even clearer than built in count function?

Comment: @arsho Never said "It's clearer" than anything. Just said it's clear as in it's clear to read.

Comment: how a loop + counting is more clear to read than `str.count('a')` ?